# NSPopupButton,list of mounted Volumes

Tags: objective-c, arrays, nspopupbutton, volumes

all.
I'm new in objective-c, and my question regard how to connect my PupupButton to see a list of my volumes as attached USB hard drive etc...to be selectable:

MyController.h

```
@interface MyController : NSWindowController <NSWindowDelegate, NSTableViewDataSource, NSTabViewDelegate, NSApplicationDelegate, NSOpenSavePanelDelegate>
{
@private    
#if !__has_feature(objc_arc)
    NSPopUpButton *_targetdevicePopup;
// etc
#endif

    NSArray*_arrayTargetdevice;
}

#if !__has_feature(objc_arc)
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet NSPopUpButton *targetdevicePopup;
//etc
#else
@property (assign) IBOutlet NSPopUpButton *targetdevicePopup;
/etc
#endif
// -- //
```

this on my .m:

```
#import "MyController.h"
#import "AppDelegate.h"
#import <IOKit/IOKitLib.h>
#import <DiskArbitration/DiskArbitration.h>
@interface MyController ()

@end

@implementation MyController
#if !__has_feature(objc_arc)
@synthesize targetdevicePopup     = _targetdevicePopup;
//etc
#endif

#if !__has_feature(objc_arc)
- (void)dealloc
{
    [_targetdevicePopup release];
//etc
}
#endif


- (id)init
{
    self = [super initWithWindowNibName:@"MyController"];
    if (self) {

    }
    return self;

}

- (void)windowDidLoad
{
    [super windowDidLoad];

//more code    

    _arrayTargetdevice = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:
                        [[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] mountedRemovableMedia], nil];

    [_targetdevicePopup addItemsWithTitles:_arrayTargetdevice];
    for (int i = 0; i <= [_arrayTargetdevice count]; i++) {
        [[_targetdevicePopup itemAtIndex:i] setTag:i];
    }

    [[[_targetdevicePopup menu]
      itemWithTitle:@"Not Selected"] setTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"Not Selected", nil)];

//more code
}
```

I would like a list of my devices (removable and not), but I get this error:

```
 - [__NSArrayI IsEqualToString:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x60800001e110
```

I would also like to write disk identifier on to a plist file ... but I stopped on the error above.

Any advice?

Comment: The code you posted is OK. I think the problem lies in those parts that you've cut out (`//more code`).

Comment: Thanks for the reply.
The missing code, concerns other PopupButton(s), with their arrays and their statements. Everything is ok without all code around the "_targetdevicePopup" (unfortunately).
I do not have adequate knowledge in OBJ-C, but I would say that the error is as if the type of data released by array is not suitable to be displayed as "addItemsWithTitles"..But like I said I've got nothing figured out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrong initialization of the array

```
_arrayTargetdevice = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:
                        [[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] mountedRemovableMedia], nil];
```

It should be

```
_arrayTargetdevice = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:
                        [[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] mountedRemovableMedia]];
```